# Managing an iphone app from another app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

We have an architecture where we have a library that we use to automate the application A, which is closely coupled with the app. (Directly linked within A). We had to write a wrapper around the library for customizations within A.

Now we want to separate the library from the application A's code and port wrapper out of A.

For this, we thought of creating a workspace and managing multiple projects there.

Now, the part where I am stuck is, I have to write an app B that links this library and application A. All the wrapper code we wrote for A should reside in this app B. None of the code should reside in the A's repository. B can be anything, that helps Automate A without effecting A's repository. A will have no reference of library / B.

Is there any way we can do it?

Can we do this by making B as a plugin for A? If so, is there any way to support this? I am very new to this, so any kind of guidance is greatly appreciated.

PS: I do not want to launch an app from other. Instead, I want an app to be running, and a way to manipulate it via external source than the application itself.

If any information is missing, please let me know.

Thanks,
RKS

Comment: Are you talking about static lib here or framework?

Comment: As an anser to PS, the only external source than can do it is the user :)

Comment: They both are iOS apps. And I am trying to hook up a custom library and an application within another application to do my job. I am not sure whether I should use an application for this purpose or a utility / plugin. I am out of options. If you can suggest me anything it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom URL scheme in application A.
In application B simply call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:myURL].
Finally application A get called through application:handleOpenURL:

See also:

- [Communicating with Other Apps](http://handleopenurl.com/)
- [URL scheme index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

Comment: I already mentioned, I do not want to launch an app from other app. I want to be able to manage one app via a way(that I am not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a way to do this. Here is how it goes:

Workspace:
    * Generic library
    * Application Code
    * Library overriding Application specific code, where all the extensions / additions reside.

Scheme:
    Created a scheme for the workspace, with following settings:
       * Application Specific library with Generic library added as a dependent build
       * Application Code having BOTH libraries added as dependent.

It works Wonders!!! :)